# Storing data into an array and then accessing it one by one in a while loop

Tags: php

---

### Background

---

- I have a table in a database made using MySql which includes several
  columns. Two of these are "name" and "address".
- I have a function written in PHP which takes in two addresses and
  returns the distance between them using Google maps API. This
  function works.

---

### Objective

---

- I want to take the two columns in the table "name" and "address" and
  store them in a variable on PHP. I then want to compare the distance
  of each row in the column "address" to an address that is hardcoded
  in the script and find out the one with the shortest distance. Once I
  find out the address with the shortest distance, I echo the "name" it
  is associated with.

---

### Problem

---

My issue is my lack of understanding of how to implement the search and storage of the data . So far I have this to try to access each address and calculate the distance:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, address FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$distance = []; // an array so we can store our distance result in here
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $distance[] = [
  'name' => $row['name'], // user id so you can use it later
  'distance' => getDistance($row['address'],$addressTo)
] // get the distance from api and save it on an array
  }
}

// now somehow have to get the min distance and name associated with it from that array
```

1. This does not even compile for some reason, gives a parse error at the end of the while loop

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

2. The way I am approaching this isnt very effective (at least with my understanding of arrays in other languages) due to my limited understanding of how arrays work in PHP. Is there a function or a way where I could effectively extract the address and the associated name that comes with it to perform this? I would appreciate some help with this.

---

### Distance function

---

For reference

```
function getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, $unit = ''){
    // Google API key
    $apiKey = ' The API key';
    
    // Change address format
    $formattedAddrFrom    = str_replace(' ', '+', $addressFrom);
    $formattedAddrTo     = str_replace(' ', '+', $addressTo);
    
    // Geocoding API request with start address
    $geocodeFrom = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddrFrom.'&sensor=false&key='.$apiKey);
    $outputFrom = json_decode($geocodeFrom);
    if(!empty($outputFrom->error_message)){
        return $outputFrom->error_message;
    }
    
    // Geocoding API request with end address
    $geocodeTo = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddrTo.'&sensor=false&key='.$apiKey);
    $outputTo = json_decode($geocodeTo);
    if(!empty($outputTo->error_message)){
        return $outputTo->error_message;
    }
    
    // Get latitude and longitude from the geodata
    $latitudeFrom    = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitudeFrom    = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    $latitudeTo        = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitudeTo    = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    
    // Calculate distance between latitude and longitude
    $theta    = $longitudeFrom - $longitudeTo;
    $dist    = sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) +  cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist    = acos($dist);
    $dist    = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles    = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    
    // Convert unit and return distance
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);
    if($unit == "K"){
        return round($miles * 1.609344, 2).' km';
    }elseif($unit == "M"){
        return round($miles * 1609.344, 2).' meters';
    }else{
        return round($miles, 2).' miles';
    }
}
```

Comment: I have found this: 

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php

Might be easier to put database into this type of structure as it has indexing?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon, please do make an effort to check for basic errors before posting. The remainder of your question is too broad and should be narrowed down to a specific problem.

Comment: @miken32 I have checked, I am simply new to the language and not fully familiar with the syntax, would appreciate if you could let me know where it is meant to go!

Comment: The end of your array definition. Consistent indentation will make spotting errors like that easier; I recommend coding to a spec such as PSR-12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over every entry in your database and making an API call in loop is going to be pretty slow.  Also, I notice that your distance calculation is being performed from the lat and lng, and isn't being directly returned by the API.

You will have a lot better performance (especially if you are planning on having any serious amount of data), to store the lat and lng for each address in the database (meaning you would only have to make the call once for each new address), and then perform the calculation without the API call.

Even better would be to just rewrite the query so that it performs the calculation and returns the top result.  Take a look at this db fiddle, with some random cities in it.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=56014857919d57a9465938982caced7f

I have output two versions of the query, one where it shows all results sorted by distance, and one where it limits to to the top result, just so you could see all of the cities ranked.

I have not checked the distance formula.  I tried to do a straight transcription from your code, and I did not verify that it was accurate, I just got it working in mySQL, and the sorting of the cities seems right.  I didn't convert into miles or anything else, so you might want to check my formula there, but I assume you know more about the correct formula than I do.  I'm just supplying some SQL here.

Handle the unit conversion in php after you've calculated the results.

Depending on how much data you expect to have, doing an unlimited self join like this could slow down.  There are ways to handle for this, but since I don't know exactly what your data will look like I think that's a topic for another time.

Also, there is a POINT data type in mySQL which is probably better suited for this type of work, and can take a spatial index, which would probably make any queries against the data more performant, and if there will be a lot of data it may be worth looking into.  I just have personally never used it, so I just went with the lat and lng stored separately in DECIMALs.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-data-formats.html

Comment: I have found this: php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php  Might be easier to put database into this type of structure as it has indexing

Comment: I have updated the post with a working example and some links to the POINT data type.  I would actually let mySQL handle this, instead of trying to do the calculations in php.  I think it will be much more performant.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that this is just an idea on how to store the data and a query.  Although most of the work would now be done in php, you will need to implement the query in php, but it looks like you already know how to do that.  I would strongly warn you, though, that if any query parameters come from user input you need to parameterize the query, or take some other measures to sanitize the inputs.  If you don't you risk loss of data and even system intrusion, either accidentally or by malicious actors.

Comment: Did this get you pointed in the right direction?

Comment: thank you very much for your help, someone thought this was a question about parsing error which it is not and closed this, completely uncalled for but thats stack overflow for you.

I have looked at what you have sent me and it is what I was looking for, although its more on SQL I am trying to implement it using PHP so it can be used with HTML java etc.

But this is definitively in the right direction and works perfectly thank you.

@chris strickland

Comment: Sure, yes, the original question was about PHP, but I thought it would probably be a lot easier to let SQL do the heavy lifting.  There's some things you should handle in PHP and some you should handle in the DB, and you'll start to get a feel for which is which with a little experience.  If you need any help with the rest of it let me know.  Looks like you do know how to implement a query in php, but it will need to be sanitized and you will likely need some kind of scheduled job to fetch long and lat for new addresses.

Comment: You are correct in that regard, processing using SQL is more efficient as I have come to learn. Regarding the long and lat, the address information is obtained from a form and stored directly into a database using PHP,  in which case I could use the PHP function shown above to directly find the long and lat and store it. This Link if used would be sent to only a small group of people and so I do not see people abusing the address to increase API costs etc but I guess it could happen.

Comment: Could you please expand on your point regarding sanitising queries in PHP? This is how one could query the result on PHP?
$sql = "SELECT results from users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


In this case result would a column of all the results and you could just echo/print it on screen but maybe not so friendly to try display on a web etc.

Comment: If you construct a query from raw user input it's dangerous. For instance, let's say you have a variable $name and you let the user enter it and you run this query: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$name'", where you dynamically insert the user input. The user could enter something like `"; DROP _db or table name here_;` and they have inserted their own query after yours, in this case a command to delete the entire table, but if you have unsanitized inputs they can run just about anything, and given the right circumstances read data or passwords out of the file system, and breach your system

Comment: Oh wow okay, that is malicious. I will look into this thank you.